Prime number as divisor
I was doing a question and I observed a thing that I'm not able to prove, it follows:
For any prime number $n>2$ , there must be only one solution $k=n-1%$ (given that $0<k<n-1$ ) to the following:
$$n |(k)!\sum_{i=1}^{k}{1/i}$$ (n is a divisor of the thing on the right)
For instance, in the case that $n=5$, $k=4$ is the only solution
I'm finding if there's a way to prove it, and can the identity be used to find other identity about prime numbers?
(I'm sorry if my expression is unclear)

This is not true. Take $p=11$. Then $3!\cdot(1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3})$ is divisible by $p$.
It is, however, true that $p-1$ always gives a solution (assuming that $p$ is odd, as you do). This can be seen by working mod $p$ -- then the factor of $k!$ is a unit that doesn't matter, and you're just summing up all the residue classes (shuffled since you're inverted them), which cancel pairwise.
